# Has my rep been annihilated by a bounty without a destination?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

Last week I put a bounty on [this answerless question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27496004/560648) (for a hat, *ahem*) and, last night, the bounty expired.

Initially I thought all the warnings that the bounty was about to expire (and that my rep would be automatically allocated to one of the answers) was buggy, there being no answers on the question. But now the bounty has expired and my +50 donation is nowhere to be seen.

So where has my rep gone? Has it gone to the Treasury? Into the coffers of Spolsky & co. for hookers and champagne? Annihilated altogether?

[image: rep goes away]
[image: but it does come back]

Comment: Why do you expect to get a +50? If there are no answers, the bounty does not get refunded.

Comment: The bounty cost is meant to pay for the additional attention it gets on the bounty board. Even if it still yields no answers, the cost is incurred for listing it as a bounty.

Comment: The rep is basically assigned to a mysterious "unawarded" bucket on the question.  If the question were to ever be deleted, you would actually get the rep back.  But if the question is undeleted again, you would lose the rep again.

Comment: This is the funniest post this Christmas.  I take my hat off to you :)

Comment: well IIRC, the page explaining how bounty works is pretty clear about the fact that once you open a bounty, you lose everything, whether the bounty is given or not.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: Because it was not awarded to anyone. It should go _somewhere_. This might be a good way to destroy reputation and help defeat rep inflation....

Comment: This is pretty different to any other sort of bounty. Do companies lose bug bounties that aren't awarded? Etc. Maybe worth making this clear, as it doesn't work the same way as the analogy it's named after.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reputation for the bounty is gone as soon as you issue it. It doesn't matter if it ends up on an answer or not, you don't get it back at the end of the bounty period.

Reputation isn't a zero-sum game, so it doesn't really have to "go" anywhere. It's just a number that gets increased or decreased.

Comment: Right, I always forget that.

Comment: I wish my accountants and auditors had the same attitiude.